# How to set validation rules in Razor instead of model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use some class from shared library as model class. That is why I can't change it(add some attributes or anything alse). But I need to add validation on my page where I use that class as @model.
Of course I can validate model by js, but I wonder are there any way to add validation rules in Razor view by standart microsoft mvc methods?
I mean something like that

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => (THERE IS MY VALIDATION EXPRESSION), "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Then use a view model with validation attributes applied to its properties and map your data model to it. In order to get client side validation using the data model, you would need to add all the appropriate `data-val-*` attributes manually and then manually check everything again in the controller when you submit the form

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but it offers an alternative. There's a project called Fluent Validation which allows you to create the validation rules for a model outside of the model. https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: AndyJ, thank you I will try

Comment: Stephen Mueske, I don't want to use attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box ASP.NET MVC does not provide the ability to validate a model within Razor. Unfortunately, this is one of the problems with using attributes for model validation.

From here you have two options available to you:

1. Create an intermediary class that then maps back to your model within the assembly.
2. Use a validation library like [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) that allows you to create validation rules without having access to the model via a flexible and extensible fluent API. For example:

.

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {

    public CustomerValidator() {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
    }

    private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
        // custom postcode validating logic goes here
    }
}
```

You then validate your model like so:

```
var validator = new YourModelValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(yourModel);
```

Personally, I would opt for the second approach. Fluent Validation is a fantastic library that doesn't take long to implement and is a much better way of validating your models than ASP.NET's current implementation (in my opinion - though that's no slur on the ASP.NET guys, this is what makes OSS great).

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it in Razor but it is possible if your shared library class is partial then you can do this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeSharedValidation))]
public partial class EmployeeShared
{
  private class EmployeeSharedValidation
  {
     [Required]
     public string Name; 
  }
}
```

This is how validation attribites were applied on EntityFramework classes which are essentially shared classes few years ago its not considered a good practice.
As its been mentioned in one of the comments, you should use a view model  because  The field will always have this validation for any page its used in . E.g Name field in the code above will be mandatory for any page the EmployeeShared class is used on , you could not change it easily.